# Using RestEasy, how can I use a @HeaderParam annotation on the properties of one of the incoming object parameters?

Tags: java, http, annotations, http-headers, resteasy

Using RestEasy, can I use a `@HeaderParam`, `@PathParam`, or `@QueryParam` annotations on the properties of one of the incoming object parameters?

This is my method:

```
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@POST
@Path("/test/{testPathParam}")
@Produces(value = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public Response test(
        @HeaderParam("testHeaderParam") String testHeaderParam,
        @QueryParam("testQueryParam") String testQueryParam,
        @PathParam("testPathParam") String testPathParam,
        TestInputBean testInputBean
) {
    Logger.info(this, "testHeaderParam:                    ", testHeaderParam);
    Logger.info(this, "testQueryParam:                     ", testQueryParam);
    Logger.info(this, "testPathParam:                      ", testPathParam);
    Logger.info(this, "testInputBean.getTestHeaderParam(): ", testInputBean.getTestHeaderParam());
    Logger.info(this, "testInputBean.getTestQueryParam():  ", testInputBean.getTestQueryParam());
    Logger.info(this, "testInputBean.getTestPathParam():   ", testInputBean.getTestPathParam());
    Logger.info(this, "testInputBean.anotherParam():       ", testInputBean.anotherParam);
    return null;
}
```

This is `TestInputBean` (deleted the getters and setters):

```
public class TestInputBean {
    @HeaderParam("testHeaderParam")
    String testHeaderParam;
    @QueryParam("testQueryParam")
    String testQueryParam;
    @PathParam("testPathParam")
    String testPathParam;
    String anotherParam;
}
```

This is the request:

[image: Request details]

This is the output:

```
testHeaderParam:                    testHeaderParam-fromHeader
testQueryParam:                     testQueryParam-fromQuery
testPathParam:                      testPathParam-fromPath
testInputBean.getTestHeaderParam(): null
testInputBean.getTestQueryParam():  null
testInputBean.getTestPathParam():   null
testInputBean.anotherParam():       anotherParam-fromJson
```

But this is what I want:

```
testHeaderParam:                    testHeaderParam-fromHeader
testQueryParam:                     testQueryParam-fromQuery
testPathParam:                      testPathParam-fromPath
testInputBean.getTestHeaderParam(): testHeaderParam-fromHeader
testInputBean.getTestQueryParam():  testQueryParam-fromQuery
testInputBean.getTestPathParam():   testPathParam-fromPath
testInputBean.anotherParam():       anotherParam-fromJson
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know if it works with RESTEasy, but with Jersey, adding `@BeanParam` to the `TestInputBean` method parameter would work. The entity body should be a separate object property inside the bean though. The JSON properties should not be inside the `TestInputBean`, but encapsulated in a separate object. I say I am not sure with RESTEasy because of the entity body. I don't know if that support is specific to Jersey or not. You can try it though

Comment: Yeah, so I just testes with with RESTEeasy, and you can't put the entity bean inside the `@BeanParam` bean. Best you might get is all the `@XxxParam` parameters inside the `@BeanParam` bean, and just keep the entity bean as a separate method parameter

Comment: I just took away all the testInputBean properties except for the header one, took away all other params from the method except for testInputBean, and removed everything but the header from the request. And I changed the verb to GET. And I got "400: java.io.EOFException: No content to map to Object due to end of input". I think it sees an object and expects JSON.

Comment: What I mean is `post(@BeanParam BeanWithParams bean, JsonBean body)`, where `bean` is a bean with all the `@XxxParam` properties. With Jersey, you could actually put the `JsonBean` as a property in the `BeanWithParams` class, but testing with RESTEasy, it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Thanks! It's `@Form`, not `@BeanParam`, but that seems to work!

Comment: You should add a response so I can mark it as an answer

Comment: I know RESTEasy has a specific `@Form`, but does `@BeanParam` not work? `@BeanParam` is standard JAX-RS (2.0).

Comment: I'm using jaxrs-api 2.3.6.Final (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.resteasy/jaxrs-api/2.3.6.Final)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all the `@XxxParam` properties into a bean, using the `@BeanParam` annotation, but I don't think it is possible to also include the JSON entity bean into this bean. You will just need to put is as a separate parameter.

```
public class Bean {
    @PathParam("id")
    private String id;
    @XxxParam("..")
    private String param;
    // getters and setters
}

@POST
public Response(@BeanParam Bean bean, JsonBody entity) {}
```

`@BeanParam` is standard JAX-RS (2.0) annotation, but RESTEasy has a specific `@Form` annotation that works exactly the same way as `@BeanParam`. See [here for more info](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.16.Final/userguide/html/_Form.html). If you are using RESTEasy 2.x, then you can only use [`@Form`](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/2.3.7.Final/userguide/html/_Form.html), as RESTEasy 2.x still used JAX-RS 1.x, which doesn't have `@BeanParam`.

Comment: Put another way, the input object is either getting its data from `@HeaderParam`, `@PathParam`, `@QueryParam`, etc (by using `@Form` or `@BeanParam` on the method param), or it's getting its data from the JSON (by not using the `@Form`). Not both.